# Why does Google chrome keep rendering the different font size of my Html document

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to create a portfolio site for my students but I have a problem. Pls can someone explain to me why
The font size of the list tag and below are so small in Google chrome. If I open my code with Google chrome it seems to me there is uneven font size for text for no reason as I haven't set any font size for anything yet, pls I need help on this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <title>programming tutorials Website</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  body {
      background-image: url(white.jpg);
      background-size: cover;
      color: black;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    p {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 3;
    }
    
    h2 {
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    .hello {
      width: 110%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    /*   .you{
    postion:relative;
    top:0%;
   float:right;
   float:top; 
 transform:translatey(-80%) translatex(4%) scaley(.7);
   /* margin:0px;
    display:block;
   
    
    z-index:-1;
    opacity:0.2;
    width:110%;
    
    
    }
    h2 h1{
    font-size:100%;
    border:0px;
    margin:0%;
    
    }
    .boxofwel, .smile{
    margin:0px;
    border:0px black solid;
    font-size:120%;
    }
    .smile{
    margin:0%;
    width:40%;
    }
    
    .wel{color:purple;
    
    }
    table{
    margin-bottom:10%;}
    ol{text-transform:uppercase;}
    
    .float{
   transform:translatey(-60%) translatex(10%)
    /*(scale(1.5)*/
    
    ;
    display:block;
    /*position:relative;
    bottom:20em;*
    /*margin-top:-20px;
   transform:translatey(500px);*/
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="boxofwel">
        <h2>
          Hello you welcome to
          <h1 class="wel">
            Eddy's Programming verse </h1>
        </h2>
      </td>
      <td class="smile"><img src="hello.jpg" class="hello">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>


  <p>
    Mostly i will be offering tutorials on web development which include programming languages like
    <!--<list>
  <ol>
  <li><b>HTML</b></li>
  <li><b>CSS</b></li>
  <li><b>javascript</b></li>
  <li><b>PHP</b></li>
   
  </ol>

  </list>-->
  </p>

  <p>
    <img src="you.jpg" class="you">


    <div class="float">


      In that order So what are waiting for get on board this and become a web developer

      <div><img src="time.jpg" width="70%"></div>



      I want you to know that ill be fully committed one helping you be the baddest programmer around

      <!--<video src="vid.mp4" controls >
  
  video aint supported
  
  
  </video>
  
  
  
  <progress >
  
  </progress>
  
  <button>
  progress
  </button>-->

    </div>
  </p>
</body>
```

Comment: Hello, i have turned your code sample into a snippet. You can edit it again to better demonstrate your issue . For instance, it does not show your list. ( `float:top;` never existed BTW)

Answer (score 0):

You have errors in your CSS due to mismatch in commenting. Just make a class for li and increase the font size.

```
.li {
font-size: 18px
}

<li class="li"> HTML </li>
<li class="li"> CSS </li>
<li class="li"> Javascript </li>
<li class="li"> PHP </li>
```

Comment: Apologies the list was commented out, so I'm getting reduced font size starting from the second paragraph tag in Google chrome and that's what I need help with as everything inside that second <p> tag has a smaller font size for some reason